# Cocos2D - Make sprite smoothly follow & rotate to touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to make a sprite to smoothly follow & rotate according to touch on the screen. The player is not forced to touch on the sprite itself to make it move, as he can only control one sprite at a time. So wherever the touch is on the screen, the player must follow the movement. Here's what I have so far :

In **GameScene.m** :

```
- (BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    lastTouchLocation = location;

    return YES;
}

- (void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    //moveBy determine the translate vector
    CGPoint moveBy = ccpSub(lastTouchLocation, location);
    [player moveBy:moveBy];

    lastTouchLocation = location;
}
```

And here's **Player.m** :

```
- (float) calculateAngleForNextPoint:(CGPoint) point
{
    CGPoint nextPoint = point;
    CGPoint pos = self.position;

    float offX = nextPoint.x - pos.x;
    float offY = nextPoint.y - pos.y;

    float angle = atan2f(offY, offX);
    angle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle);
    angle = -angle + 90;

    return angle;
}

- (void) moveBy:(CGPoint)_pos
{
    CGPoint newPos = ccpSub(self.position, _pos);
    float angle = [self calculateAngleForNextPoint:newPos];

    self.position = newPos;
    self.rotation = angle;   

}
```

This code works well, but the rotation is not smooth at all, mainly when the player moves his finger slowly on the screen, the sprite goes crazy! I tried many things, like setting up actions, but the touchMoved method is called too rapidly to use Actions.

What should I do to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You aren't factoring in that movement and rotation should probably occur over time, not instantly. If you tie movement & rotation directly to touch movement without interpolating either the touch location or the movement behavior, what you see is probably the effect that touch updates can be quite "jumpy" and not a smooth, gradual change.

Comment: I do something similar in Claustrophobic, but everything is done via actions when changing rotation, etc.  The sprite should 'target' the new angle, not jump to it.  It will be much smoother then.

Comment: But since touchMoved is called really rapidly, actions will be overwritten everytime, so how did you do that with actions?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a Physics Engine (chipmunk, box2d, ...) and have a damped spring between your finger position and your sprite.

If you can't afford a physics engine in your game, and you want a smooth real-life like movement, you should keep the sprite position, velocity and acceleration (idem for angle, angular velocity, angular acceleration). Your finger movement will then update the accelerations (like a spring would do), and you then start a scheduler to update the velocity and position 60 times/second.

That's how I'd do it